# CoreData and notifying background workers about change in main thread

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I thought I had a pretty simple situation, but after whole day of searching I am not sure I have an answer !!!

I am using CoreData (by actually using RestKit and `[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore`). I save data to store only on the main thread. Though I have a lot of background threads that read data from DB. I cannot find any good approach of notifying those background threads, if main thread (with main `NSManagedObjectContext`) saves data to DB.

The only approach I see is to keep a list of all background threads' `NSManagedObjectContexts` and send each of them `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` when handiling `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` on main thread.

Is this normal way of dealing with this situation? I have a feeling that not due to potential problems that may arise with managing that kind of cache in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Why do you need to notify these threads? How many threads do you have? What type of threads do you use? And yes, `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` is the correct way to notify them.

Answer (score 0):

With no details it's difficult to understand what is going on, but yes, use `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` in background threads.

But be careful, if you create a lot of threads that listen for changes, battery could go down very rapidly.

Based on my experience, threads in Core Data should be used as the following: create one or more threads that perform some request in a shared persistent store coordinator. When threads have finished stop (remove) them. This sort of mechanism allows you to load data in the cache of the store coordinator, speeding up future requests performed in the main thread.

Hope that helps.

P.S. I don't know how RestKit works with Core Data.